# "Until afternoon" or "until the afternoon"?

Tags: definite-article

Tell me please if I need to use *the* before *afternoon* in the following sentence.

> On Fridays I work until (**the**) afternoon.

I am aware that generally *the* is used with *afternoon*, but what about my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't usually incorrect to drop the article, but we would be more likely to say "until *the* afternoon". [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until%20afternoon%2C%20until%20the%20afternoon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntil%20afternoon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20the%20afternoon%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cuntil%20afternoon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20the%20afternoon%3B%2Cc0) shows the frequency with which they are both used.

As you probably realise, "afternoon" is a compound of the words *after* and *noon*. Noon is midday (another compound word!). As a compound noun, it refers to the whole time from 12 noon until whatever time you class as "evening". As two separate words, it just means anything after 12pm, so their usage is a little different.

Looking at your example, I don't think either is correct. This is because you are using the word "until", which means *up to a specific point*. Neither "after noon" nor "afternoon" are specific points in time.

I think you should say:

> On Fridays I work *until noon*.

Comment: *"On Fridays I work until noon."* - Unless, of course, you work until some non specific (and varying) time in the afternoon.